# Recover data to a drop down list from an external data

Tags: text-files, jira, external, recover

Is this possible to recover data from an external source, in order to enrich the contents of a drop-down list? If it is possible, what form or should the JIRA project administrator add manually new data in drop-down list?
Should I use a plugin to do that?

For example : 
I have a select list with operating system, which contains Windows, Linux, Mac 
Somewhere on the network, I have a textfile which contain several lines with one operating system by line. 
Is this possible to recover 'Unix' text from this textfile written in line 4 ?